# DAX code change from calculated column to a measure

Tags: dax, calculated-columns, measure

I have a fact table with settlement_date, product_id, service_id, location_id, and ticket_id and srv_adjusted_earning columns.

I have determined the DAX query to generate a calculated column that sums the srv_adjusted_earning column over the date range: settlement date and settlement date - 27 days (i.e. a 4 week window) as:

```
=CALCULATE(
    SUM(factService[SRV_ADJUSTED_EARNING]),
    DATESBETWEEN
    (
        factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE],
        DATEADD(factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE], -27, DAY), 
        factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE]
    ),
    FILTER(factService, factService[PRO_ID] = EARLIER(factService[PRO_ID])),
    FILTER(factService, factService[SER_ID] = EARLIER(factService[SER_ID])),
    FILTER(factService, factService[LOC_ID_SELLING] = 
        EARLIER(factService[LOC_ID_SELLING])),
    FILTER(factService, factService[TIS_ID] = EARLIER(factService[TIS_ID]))
)
```

I am trying to convert this DAX calculated column to a measure and I tried the following:

```
blob:=CALCULATE
(
    SUM(factService[SRV_ADJUSTED_EARNING]),
    DATESBETWEEN
    (
        factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE], 
        DATEADD(factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE], -27, DAY), 
        factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE]
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT(factService, factService[PRO_ID]),
    ALLEXCEPT(factService, factService[SER_ID]),
    ALLEXCEPT(factService, factService[LOC_ID_SELLING]),
    ALLEXCEPT(factService, factService[TIS_ID])
)
```

But I get:
Error: Calculation error in measure 'factService'[blob]: A single value for column 'SETTLEMENT_DATE' in table 'factService' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Anybody know how I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mentions, the issue is with `factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE]`. In the measure, there is no row context so that it knows which date you are talking about, so you need to specify it somehow. I'd suggest using a variable along these lines:

```
blob :=
VAR SettleDate = MAX ( factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( factService[SRV_ADJUSTED_EARNING] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            factService[SETTLEMENT_DATE],
            SettleDate - 27,
            SettleDate
        ),
        ALLEXCEPT (
            factService,
            factService[PRO_ID],
            factService[SER_ID],
            factService[LOC_ID_SELLING],
            factService[TIS_ID]
        )
    )
```

Here the variable picks the maximal settlement date in the current filter context. If that's not exactly what you need, adjust the definition accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That throws the error: "Semantic error: the first argument to "DATEADD" must specify a column.

Also I am looking to take the dates 28 relative to the date in the row, so given Feb 28th that would be 1st to 28th Feb inclusive.  Wouldn't the MAX take the largest date in the fact?

Comment: Ah, I forgot `DATEADD` needs a date column as the first argument. As far as the `MAX` goes, it takes the max in the current filter context, not necessarily over the whole fact table. Try my edit.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response.  That solves the semantic error and you are correct that the MAX is in the filter context.  I have created the calculated field and compared to the calculated column and the answers are the same, and I have marked your post as the correct answer.  I trawled the net and the Russo/Ferrari book for an answer without joy so I cannot thank you enough for your post.  Nice trick to use the variable to force the filter context - I won't forget that one.